# How do I save a Geotiff from Julia? From Omniscape tutorial

Tags: julia, save, gis

I'm a total newbie to Julia and started by working my way through this tutorial https://docs.circuitscape.org/Omniscape.jl/latest/examples/ on wildlife habitat connectivity. How can I save the resulting GeoTiff files to my local computer. e.g., to save normalized_cum_currmap.tif. I've been playing around with 'write' and 'export' commands, but no success. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you provided the root directory in the config file via the mapping `"project_name" => "md_nlcd_omniscape_output"`? I've just run the example and it works as expected. All output is directly written to the directory `md_nlcd_omniscape_output`.

Comment: Aha! I had done that, but assumed the root directory was just held in temporary memory. Indeed, it is written where you said. Thank you!